# Returning an object which is defined by another local object

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I am wondering how to make a function return an object that is dependent of another object or pointer which does not exist outside the function. The situation is the following:

To sort a `std::map` there is a custom comparator function declared inside a class `Object`. This function must be a static member of a class or a global function in order to be passed to `std::map`:

```
static bool RenderOrderComparator(const Object *Obj, float a, float b);
```

This function must access some member of an instance of `Object` to compare two given floating point numbers correctly (non-trivial). Now I want to have another function which is used at several places in the respective unit to do the sorting:

```
X Object::SortInstances(const Camera &Cam)
{
    auto comp = std::bind(RenderOrderComparator, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    std::map<float, const ObjectTransformation &, decltype(comp)> SortedInstances(comp);

    // ... do some stuff and fill the map

    return SortedInstances;
}
```

The idea here was to use `std::bind` to bind `this` to the comparator function in order to access the required member. My question is now what do I have to write in the place of X? What is the type of the map I am actually intending to return? I tried something like

```
std::map<float, const ObjectTransformation &, decltype(std::bind(Object::RenderOrderComparator, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2))>
```

which logically cannot work because `this` is not known outside the definition of the function. Also I played - unsuccessfully - with `std::result_of`. Do you have any solution for that problem?

I am looking foreward to your help.

Yours Julian

Comment: What about replacing `this` with `X{}` or something?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. My question was, what X actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This function must be a static member of a class or a global function in order to be passed to `std::map`

Where did this requirement come from? `std::map` supports comparators that are not functions, but objects with `operator()` a.k.a. *functors*.

```
struct RenderOrderComparator {
    Object const * scene_or_whatever;

    bool operator() ( float a, float b ) {
        return … ;
    }
};
```

Use `RenderOrderComparator` as the third template argument to `std::map`. There should be no need for `std::bind`, which as it happens only produces such an object with an `operator()` member.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. But I am still very interested whether there is any approach to solve my original problem. I cannot believe that there is no way to determine the type of the return value even though I do not know how to get it.

Comment: @JulianBopp Just replace `this` with an expression of type `Object *`. Since the operand of `decltype` is unevaluated, only types matter, not values. You could use `static_cast< Object * >( nullptr )` or `std::declval< Object * >()`.